# Optimize visits so the distance of all attendees is nearly equal

Tags: optimization

We've got 5 persons: A,B,C,D and E.
Each persons has a specific distance to each other person.

For example:
[image: Distance for each person to each other person]

Each year, those persons have to meet x times on one of the persons house.
How am I supposed to calculate how ofter everyone has to host a meeting so everyone has approximately the same distance to travel?

Comment: Not necessarily relevant to your question: The distances are inconsistent.  For instance A to C is distance $4.3$; C to B is distance $2$.  But A to B is $10$.  Certainly A could go to C and then on to B for a total distance of $6.3$.  I.e., the triangle inequality is violated.

Comment: You need to solve for $x=1,2$ the rest follow easily enough.

Comment: @Macavity is it possible for you to give a short explanation?